# Raw query must include the primary key in custom posgresql function

Tags: django, python-3.x

i did this function with pg/sql languaje,for example: dinamico('some_string')
and i am using in a simple django views:

```
def detalle_fondo(request,fondo):
    det_fondos=f.objects.raw('select * from dinamico(%s)',[fondo])
    return render(request,'sw/det-fondos.html',{'det_fondos':det_fondos})
```

the problem is django ask me for the primary key:

> Raw query must include the primary key

but i don now how to pass a primary key throught a custom function.
Can you help me?

Comment: What is `dinamico`? Why is this raw sql linked to `model.objects`?

Answer (score 0):

Follow following approach

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('select * from dinamico(%s)', [fondo])
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            print(row)
```